# Trailhead : Build an IOT integration with Electric Imp

Tags: trailhead, iot

Trying to complete this project but can't seem to access the link to buy the electric imp developer kit.

This is the link provided on the trail:

https://connect.electricimp.com/partners/salesforcetrailhead

It returns a 404 error.

Does anyone have a work around or any other resource where we can purchase this from?

Comment: [Here is a link](https://store.electricimp.com/collections/featured-products) to all products available on the electric imp store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct link: https://store.electricimp.com/collections/featured-products/products/impexplorer-developer-kit?variant=31118866130

Here is the latest Trailhead Project for Salesforce that works with Salesforce EMP (Platform Events): https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-electric-imp